# Responding in postdoc interview

Tags: research-process, postdocs, interview

In a postdoc interview, I was asked about something that I didn't know, and I said I don't have a professional experience into that however I am willing to know more about it. Although, this was not something I needed to know and not mentioned in my CV. So I am not sure I reacted well enough. How should I deal with such kind of questions in the future?

Thanks

Comment: Did they give some indication that they didn't think you reacted well? I actually think that's an entirely appropriate response. If they interviewed you with no reason to believe that you knew about that topic then the they can't, and you responded by expressing willingness to learn about the topic then that's the best you can do.

Comment: In my company we use questions like that to see 1. how willing a person is to learn things outside of their interest/comfort zone 2. to kind of test the waters to see how someone responds to possibly not knowing something and 3. see if they have a plan as to how they would find out more information about a new subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you reacted fairly well.  I've been in many interviews, and been asked all sorts of questions that I don't know.
If it is on the job description, you should have researched it ahead of time.  It is ok to state that is an area of interest and drew you to this job (if that is true).  State that you have experience in learning new things.

If it is a specific product or buzzword, state that you don't know that product name; ask what type of thing it is, and then answer with your experience in that type of thing.

There are also "unanswerable" interview questions just to see how the interviewee responds.

I know recruiters who aim for people to be an 80-90% match, not 100% as they already know everything and will not be challenged and thus leave fairly soon.

The most important things are to stay calm, rational, and willing to research and learn whatever it is.